# Disable JavaScript in a single Firefox tab

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

In a Firefox add-on built with the Add-on SDK, how can I disable and re-enable JavaScript for a single tab?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The SDK itself doesn't provide this functionality, you will have to work with the XUL directly. What you need to do is accessing the [`docShell` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/browser#p-docShell) of the XUL `<browser>` element corresponding to the tab. The docshell has an [`allowJavascript` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIDocShell#Attributes) that lets you switch JavaScript on and off. Something like this should work:

```js
var window = require("window-utils").activeBrowserWindow;
var tabBrowser = window.gBrowser;
var browser = tabBrowser.selectedBrowser;   // or: tabBrowser.browsers[n]
browser.docShell.allowJavascript = false;
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem possible to take a [`Tab` object](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.5/packages/addon-kit/docs/tabs.html#Tab) and find the corresponding XUL element - you have to work with the XUL window from the start.

Relevant documentation:

- [`window-utils` package](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.5/packages/api-utils/docs/window-utils.html) (the properties `activeWindow`/`activeBrowserWindow` are undocumented for some reason).
- [`<tabbrowser>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/tabbrowser)
- [`<browser>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/browser)
- [`nsIDocShell` interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIDocShell)